# How to increase the size of any polygon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to map the vertices of the border of a normalized polygon (i.e centered around (0.0)) given its vertices and border thickness. I am trying to do this for a computer program. Below I provide the code. The problem is that the math is not working.

```
void polygon::increase_coordinates(GLfloat howmuch){
    GLfloat angle;
    for(auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it){
        angle = atan((it->xpos)/(it->ypos));
        it->xpos = it->xpos + cos(angle)*howmuch;
        it->ypos = it->ypos + sin(angle)*howmuch;
    }
}
```

pseudocode for the mathematicians

let $X$ be a set of vertices and $B$ the border thickness
for $\forall$ vertices $v \in X$
$\theta \leftarrow arctan (v.x / v.y)$
$v.x = v.x + cos(\theta)*B$
$v.y = v.y + sin(\theta)*B$

Is the math right? otherwise I am gonna have to take a look at my program. FYI, I am using the C library cmath to do these operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may need to use a function called `atan2(x,y)` or the like, in order to distinguish between $(x,y)=(3,4)$ and $(x,y)=(-3,-4)$, for example, and also avoid problems with division by zero.

Alternatively, avoid trigonometry altogether and write $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ and $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ instead of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Comment: Is it safe to resize back the triangle by passing howmuch as negative?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Up to possible rounding problems, yes. `increase_coordinates(42); increase_coordinates(-42);` is essentially a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

Well...it's going to fail when $v.y = 0$. Far better to use `atan2`, which handles this case gracefully...and which also handles properly the case where $v.x$ is not positive, which your program will mess up. (Try it by hand on the square with vertices $(\pm1, \pm 1)$ to see why.)

(Revised) Now that I understand what you're trying to do, here's revised code (very similar to yours):

```
void polygon::increase_coordinates(GLfloat howmuch){
    GLfloat angle;
    for(auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it){
        angle = atan2(it->ypos, it->xpos); 
        it->xpos =  it->xpos + howmuch * cos(angle);
        it->ypos =  it->ypos + howmuch * sin(angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. It's not by a factor . Imagine you have a vertex in a Cartesian plane and you go B away relative to the origin

Comment: Revised to make it do this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `atan` vs `atan2` issue, you will also have to be clearer about exactly what you want to do.

Adding a border of a fixed thickness around a polygon is not the same thing as making it larger by scaling.

Consider for example a For example a $1\times10$ rectangle.

If you add a border of thickness $1$ around it you get a rectangle that is $3\times12$, which clearly has a different ratio. It is no longer similar to the original shape. Note also that with a border thickness of $1$, the vertices have moved by a distance of $\sqrt 2$, and not in the direction away from the origin. If you apply a thick-enough border to a non-convex polygon, its non-convex parts get filled in resulting in a convex polygon.

If you want to add borders in this way, you will have to shift the edges outwards by a fixed distance (the border thickness), and then recalculate the coordinates of the vertices as the intersection of adjacent edges.

Scaling up a polygon is much simpler. Just multiply all the coordinates by a fixed factor slightly larger than $1$. Note that not all sides are moved outwards by the same distance. For example, if you scale the $1\times10$ rectangle to be $3$ wide so that the long sides have moved outwards by a distance of $1$, you also multiply the length by $3$ to become $30$ so the short sides have moved outwards a distance of $10$. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Assume the polygon is convex